# Can the main loop of a program be moved out of GUI?

Tags: python, design-patterns, user-interface, tkinter

I'm using python 3 / tkinter if that matters.

In looking at code samples I noticed that the main loop is typically in the GUI part of the code, and the rest of the code provides callbacks for GUI to call when needed.

But my simulation runs independently of the user interaction; the UI is there to provide a view, from time to time, into what's going on in the simulation, but it doesn't control what goes on in the simulation. So I would like the main loop to be concerned with the simulation rather than UI. How would I do that?

Comment: Don't know about python/tkinter, but e.g. Qt allows multiple event loops, and event loops in non-UI threads.

Comment: Is there a GUI toolkit that doesn't even require a mainloop-type construct, and which simply exposes an object whose methods can be called to display stuff? (I know it would be unusual, I'm just curious)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not seperate your logic and presentation. Write your sim backend to respond to a single text based protcol to receive cmds and send back results, and then just talk to it from your gui program over e.g. unix sockets.

Answer (score 1):

Write your own main loop that calls the functions that check for and process GUI events.

Comment: Is there anything I should be aware of if I do that? I'm just learning tk / tkinter, but my GUI needs are relatively simple.

Comment: Only that every second you don't process GUI messages is another second that your GUI remains unresponsive.

Comment: Is tkinter a reasonable tool for this particular purpose? Also, is there any reason why GUI functionality isn't usually separated into its own thread?

Comment: Sorry I'm confused: so you're saying there's a way to use tkinter without ever calling its mainloop, as long as I'm willing to write some extra code?

Comment: That's basically the gist of it, yes.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to make tkinter widgets display unless I call `mainloop`. I suspect an event to display those widgets is added to tk's event queue when I create the widget, but I can't figure out how to manually process that event (i.e., without calling `mainloop`)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should perform your processing in a separate thread, and then have the GUI thread send and receive messages to that thread.

However, do not try to directly update the GUI from the processing thread. Instead, you can send a message to the GUI using a message queue, similar to [effbot's example](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-threads.htm). The important thing is `queue.get_nowait()`: you can just periodically run this in your GUI without blocking other threads if there is nothing in the queue.

Comment: I'm referring to a separate thread. However, only the queue needs to be shared between the GUI and processing thread.